# thunderbird logs in after adding a double domain name

Tags: linux, postfix

I've spent my last few days migrating my email server to another server location, all my config files are the same etc. But for some reason i keep getting weird issue's on the new server.
I'd like to ask if anyone knows why this error happens, when trying to log in with Thunderbird, it add a 2nd domain before it is able to log in. In my case, `info@domain1.com@mail.domain1.com`

[Thunderbird image of login log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mpHkx.png)

[Image of trying to log in before the double domain](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xttus.png)

All i can think of that is the issue, is that when it logs in with the double domain identifier, it ignores the 2nd one, and thus its ignoring the subdomain mail.

Comment: It is hard to tell when without seeing the server + client configuration, but I guess the username is in form `user@example.com` instead of user, and the second domain is the hostname to connect,, resulting in `user@example.com@example.com`. You would have to configure the server to accept `user` as the username.